# InvalidBlockList error while uploading CloudBlockBlob in parallel

Tags: c#, .net, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

I have an application that uploads the CloudBlockBlob in parallel using following method

[UploadFromStreamAsync MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn434979.aspx)

```
CloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync Method (Stream, AccessCondition, BlobRequestOptions, OperationContext)
```

Sometimes I have observed that file upload is erroring due to exception mentioned below.

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol.HttpResponseParsers.ProcessExpectedStatusCodeNoException[T](HttpStatusCode expectedStatusCode, HttpStatusCode actualStatusCode, T retVal, StorageCommandBase`1 cmd, Exception ex)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.<PutBlockListImpl>b__33(RESTCommand`1 cmd, HttpWebResponse resp, Exception ex, OperationContext ctx)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndGetResponse[T](IAsyncResult getResponseResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.StorageAsyncResult`1.End()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.AsyncExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4.<CreateCallbackVoid>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at WKHMR.SSR.Common.Azure.Storage.AzureBlobStorage.<UploadFileAsync>d__32.MoveNext()


StatusMessage:The specified block list is invalid.

ErrorCode:InvalidBlockList
```

Anyone know what could be the possible cause of this error? and How to fix it?

Comment: How do you write your parallel code? Please share your code. So that we can better understand your issue.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I realized that multiple threads were trying the upload two blobs at the same location in blob storage so it was causing the block list mismatch on the server.